# Лучший и быстрый вариант проверить наличие текста в массиве

Tags: java, производительность

Здравствуйте, не стану объяснять в чём смысл всего этого кода, и сразу приступлю к проблеме.

Если bar - ArrayList, то операция завершается за 22 секунд, С LinkedList >30 сек. Есть ли другие варианты проверять наличие значения в массиве?
Производительность для меня очень важна :)

Есть код:

```
    final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        foo("test");
    }
    final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time: " + (endTime - time) + " ms");
```

Метод foo:

```
public static boolean foo(String s){
    /*Всякий код*/
    return bar.contains(s);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте HashSet.

```
ArrayList: 14475 ms
HashSet: 43 ms
Sorted ArrayList: 540 ms
```

Код:

```
    long time = 0;

    ArrayList<String> strings = new  ArrayList<String>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        strings.add(String.valueOf(rand.nextInt()));
    }

    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        strings.contains("test");
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("ArrayList: " + (endTime - time) + " ms");

    HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(strings);
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        hashSet.contains("test");
    }
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println( "HashSet:" + (endTime - time) + " ms");


    Collections.sort(strings);
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        Collections.binarySearch(strings,"test");
    }
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Sorted ArrayList:" + (endTime - time) + " ms");
```

Comment: По хорошему, сортировку для SortedList было бы неплохо внести в подсчет времени

Comment: В данном тесте время, потраченное на преобразование намного меньше самого поиска.Тут уже всё зависит от требований задачи автора, как применить, в какой момент и как часто сортировать.

Comment: Ухты, я конечно всё ожидал, но такой скорости! Спасибо большое :)